# How do i get id of colunm in gridview c# asp.net and open another page using that id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, gridview

How do i get id of column in grid view c# asp.net using a button and the open another web-part that will collect information fromsl server using that id from grid-view?

I have done this for my grid view:

```
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnView" runat="server" Text="View" /> 
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

And for the information from sqlserver that is being filled in gridview the code is:

```
   protected void GridView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DBEntitiesModelConn DbContext = new DBEntitiesModelConn())
            {
                try
                {
                    GridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                    var ApplicationData = from i in DbContext.DBEntity
                                          select new
                                          {
                                              CompanyName = i.Name.ToString(),
                                              ApplicationStatus = i.Status.ToString(),
                                              ApplicationDate = i.DateSubmitted.ToString(),
                                              ApplicationID = i.ID.ToString(),
                                          };
                    GridView.DataSource = ApplicationData.ToList();
                    GridView.DataBind();
                }
                catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                {
                    ErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(ViewApplicationsGrid, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row.";
            }
        }
```

Comment: A column does not have an ID.

Comment: My id is `ApplicationID`